# What is a difference in XOR function between python2 and python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, xor

I have two strings:

```
string1 = "\xc5\x06\x92\xd0\x02k=\x91"
string2 = "qwert\00\00\00"
```

and function:

```
def xor(str1,str2):
    ret = ''
    for i in range(8):
        ret += chr(ord(str1[i]) ^ ord(str2[i]))
    return ret
```

The result of the above function is:

in python2.7: `´�q��vk=�` ; in hex: `ef bf bd 71 ef bf bd ef bf bd 76 6b 3d ef bf bd`

in python3.6 `´q÷¢vk=‘` ; in hex: `b4 71 f7 a2 76 6b 3d 91`

I suppose this is connected with the fact that in python2 `str` type is limited to ascii, but how to get the same value in both versions ?

Comment: counter-question: why do you need to get "the same value in both versions" when 2.7 was finally and properly killed off on January 1st, 2020? There is no context in which you'll be "running either and you're not sure of which": either you're on a legacy setup that can't install and use python 3, or you're using python 3.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: Well, there is the third setup; you're writing portable modules that are used by both legacy code that hasn't been ported yet ("End of life" doesn't mean what it used to), and used by new code written directly for Python 3. I agree that when possible, you shouldn't be doing this, but sometimes that's what you're paid to do.

Comment: As an aside, you can write this as `''.join([char(ord(x)^ord(y)) for x, y in zip(str1, str2)])`, saving you from having to deal with indices explicitly.

Comment: Or `''.join(map(lambda x, y: char(ord(x)^ord(y)), str1, str2))`.

Comment: Or `''.join(map(char, map(operator.xor, map(ord, str1), map(ord, str2))))`.

Comment: @chepner: You meant `chr`, not `char` in all cases. Of course, you could speed it up further by replacing `map(ord, somestr)` with `somestr.encode('latin-1')` (Py3 only) or for portability, `bytearray(somestr, 'latin-1')`, so it does bulk decoding, then iterates by `int` natively (and `''.join(map(chr` could be `bytearray`+`decode`). Or faster (Py3 only, using `bytes` from the start, which this should already be doing, because text strings for xor-ing is nonsense), `(int.from_bytes(string1, 'little') ^ int.from_bytes(string2, 'little')).to_bytes(max(len(string1), len(string2)), 'little')`.

Answer (score 2):

It *is* the same value in both versions. You're just printing it on a locale that doesn't support some of the characters, and it's using the Unicode replacement character to display it (the `ef bf bd` sequences in your output are where a character it didn't recognize became the replacement character; whatever you used to convert to bytes seamlessly replaced the Unicode replacement character with its UTF-8 encoding).

When the locale is correct and you have terminal/font support that handles the result, it works identically on [Python 2](https://tio.run/##PY/RCsIwDEXf@xWhL2txD11B0cG@xCrI1m1FaGesWL@@tq4zhCQXDjfJ8vGzszLGp0djpwY6oCr0exXEQYWTVGEQaZb3LqmGkhWTGXu8NXolxJqUDHqE4JAlpKlTkbwlkAO1T3xVrWp0CAaMBbzZSbPjRm3kroN@RuZw@DmdzYXDFYqUWfK/7QttbmRJR3lWluc3aiiHch7jFw) and [Python 3](https://tio.run/##PY/RCsIwDEXf@xVhL2txD11FUWFfYhVk67YitDNWrF9fW9sZQpILh5tk@bjZmm0IT4faTC10UEnf76Tne@mPQvqBx1ncu6jaimRMJOzxVugk5zkrMqgRvEUakbaJRbATgRSoXOTrOqvRImjQBvBmJkUPK7WSmw76GanF4ed01hcGVyhSJMn@ti80qZElHuVoWZ7eaKAcylgIXw). The only real difference is that Python 3 has somewhat saner behaviors under some locales (e.g. [Windows console using UTF-8 automatically](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-528-change-windows-console-encoding-to-utf-8) in 3.6, [legacy C locale coercion](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-538-legacy-c-locale-coercion) in 3.7), but you got the same string, it's just outputting and displaying it that produces the wrong result while trying to avoid unencodable characters.

To be clear, Python 2 `str` is not limited to ASCII. In terms of what it can hold, it's equivalent to Python 3 `bytes`; both can hold arbitrary values in the range [0, 256). The literals differ (Py2 allows non-ASCII characters in a literal without escapes, though without a file encoding declaration, it's not portable), but Py2 `str` can hold `'\xff'` just like Py3 `bytes`'s `b'\xff'`.

Note that your code often won't work identically when the `str` contains characters outside the ASCII range that aren't inserted using escapes (it's dependent on the encoding declaration for the file what non-ASCII literal characters in a string literal mean for Python 2), and definitely won't work the same for stuff that's not in latin-1 (because it will have ordinals larger than 256 in Py3, and who knows what in Py2) unless the inputs are of `unicode` type in Python 2 (e.g. for literals, prefixed with `u`).